# Bibtex wont update/compile

Tags: bibtex

I'm using bibtex to do my references but it has stopped compiling correctly. It happened when working on a different LaTeX file (not using the same bibtex file and not in the same folder) and has been messing up on multiple LaTeX files since.

I'm using:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{FINAL}
```

The error I get is:

```
Process started: bibtex.exe "FINAL"

Process exited with error(s)
```

I've deleted temp files and recompiled and I don't have any other .bib files in the same folder. It seems to be happening for different LaTeX files in different folders, which makes me think it may be an issue with bibtex?

The bibtex file is in the same folder as the .tex file.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is the `FINAL.bib` in the documents folder?

Comment: To the editor: please, if you want to answer the question, use the proper answer space rather than edit the question itself.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I think this is a case of "Jenni" and "user52049" being the same person (multiple accounts) rather than an answerer attempting to edit the question. The proposed edit was a response to Herbert's question.

Comment: @PaulGessler: I see, but isn't better to have an answer in the proper space (regardless who answers) rather than an edit in the question? It is perfectly fine having the OP answering his own question if he finds a solution.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino, the problem is that it _doesn't_ answer the question. It only provides clarification requested by Herbert in his comment (the location of the `FINAL.bib` file).

Comment: @PaulGessler: oh my bad, now I see the point! You're absolutely right.

Comment: Please provide us with a [MWEB](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407/15925) demonstrating the problem.